# Minimax Algorithm queue possible?

Tags: data-structures, minimax

Is it possible to represent a minimax algorithm within a queue data structure or is it only possible within a tree?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if you could use a queue in the minmax algorithm? Or are you asking if the different states of the game could be represented using a queue?

Comment: The game states form a tree, with children and parents. Using a deque to go through a tree is one convenient way, either depth or breadth first. So you can implement it using a deque, but you'll still need to know which state is a child of which parent.

Answer (score 3):

If you implement minimax as a breadth-first game tree search, the FIFO nature of a queue is a natural fit for the algorithm.  You would store each position in the queue, and then all the positions that could result from that position.  Recurse until you reach your terminating search depth.  But the drawback, and it is a big one, is that there are an exponential number of terminal nodes in relation to the depth of the tree and you would have to store all of them in the queue for a breadth-first search.

Minimax is better implemented as a depth-first search, which requires only a linear amount of memory in relation to tree depth.  The data structure used for this search is a stack, either through recursive function calls or a direct stack based implementation without the function call overhead.